# Windows Permissions/Policy required to use qWAVE

Tags: c++, windows, user-permissions, qos

I'm attempting to use qWAVE (on Windows Server 2008 R2) to set arbitrary DSCP values on socket traffic.  I think I'm setting up the flow correctly, but when I try to call QOSSetFlow(), I'm getting an ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error ("The calling application does not have sufficient privileges for the requested operation.").  The user that's running this code is a member of the Administrators group, and I've looked through the various security policies but didn't see anything that looked relevant.  Does anyone know what permission I need to give the user to get this API to work?

Thanks!

UPDATE:  I've got a test program that just tries to set the DSCP values, and when I check "Run as Administrator" under the Compatibility menu everything works fine.  So the code is okay, and the Administrator User has the necessary permissions.  Unfortunately the actual service can't be run as the Administrator User.  Is there a way to give the Administrators Group (or a specific user) some of the permissions that the Administrator User has?